# java return type error and error handling

Tags: java, error-handling, return-type

I am a newbie. One methods has two errors. Please help to resolve these.

I am making file system using multi node tree.

This method returns a file/directory of given name in a subdirectory. After looping, if it doesn't have such file/directory, it should give an error.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import driver.exception.InvalidFileDirectoryException;

public class FileNode {

    private FileNode parent;
    private ArrayList<FileNode> children = new ArrayList<FileNode>();
    private String name;


    public FileNode getChild(String name) {   // This method must return a type of FileNode.
        for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
                if (children.get(i).getName() == name) {
                    return children.get(i);
                }
                if ((i == children.size()-1) 
                    && (children.get(i).getName() != name)) {
                    throw new InvalidFileDirectoryException(
                        name + ": No such file or directory");   // Unhandled exception type InvalidFileDirectoryException
                }
        }
    }
```

I can understand the first error. This method can return nothing if there is no such file or directory. However, I want to give an error message in that case. What should I do? Please help!

```
public class InvalidFileDirectoryException extends Exception {

    public InvalidFileDirectoryException() {
        super();
    }

    public InvalidFileDirectoryException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the record, as newbies often forget about it : please don't forget to accept an answer at some point. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `getChild` method to:-

```
public FileNode getChild(String name) throws InvalidFileDirectoryException {
    for (int i = 0; i < children.size(); i++) {
        if (children.get(i).getName().equals(name)) {
            return children.get(i);
        }
    }
    throw new InvalidFileDirectoryException(name + ": No such file or directory");
}
```

This will scan through the `children` collection. If a match is found, the child will be returned from this method. If the loop completed and no match was found, it will throw the exception. Notice the method signature says `throws InvalidFileDirectoryException`.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know how to properly throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

All potential paths within your method need to return a value. You can't have a method that returns a value and does not return a value!

You only return from two if statements within the loop body. What if the if statements both never have a true condition?! Thus: add a return statement and after the loop. Probably the method should return null then. If that is really an error case, you should throw an exception (unconditionally).

And it looks like you are using == to compare strings. That is wrong, you should use *equals()* instead.

Comment: What if the if statements both never have a true condition? -> I want to give an error message in that case. How do I do that? And thanks for equals().

Comment: As written: then you need some code *after* the loop. But even when printing an error message you still need a final return statement. Alternatively, throw an exception there, too (unconditionally).